# Problem with audacity

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, audacity

I'm recording Teamspeak conversations via audacity for a Let's Play. The recording sounds kind of slow, as if it was a tape, running on low battery. Very much like in this post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2174391

Unfortunatly the solution (using Audio Recorder) didn't work for me.

The funny thing is: When I tried to manually adjust the playback speed, the recording sounded normal at a 1.08 times faster playback. 48kHz divided by 44.11kHz equals roughly that factor. So I believe that it has something to do with the recording frequency. Changig that didn't help though.

Thanks in advance,

Markus